# global/inner variable conflict? (python)

Tags: python, variables

Sorry for the stupid question, I'm a newbie programmer. But can anyone tell me why the following program behaves this way?

```
def lol(a):
    a=[]
    a.append(1)
    return a
```

Now when I do

```
k = [2, 3]
lol(k)
```

It returns 1, but `k` is still unchanged? Why?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `lol(a)`, the line `a=[]` binds `a` to a new list. After this line, `a` is no longer bounded to the same list than `k`. So what you're actually modifying in your function is a **new list**, not the list that you received in argument. For further information, [see the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding).

If you want `k` to be `[1]`, then you could write something like this instead:

```
def lol(a):
    a[:] = [1]
    return a

k = [2, 3]
lol(k) # now k is equal to [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check inline comments..

```
def lol(a): # a and k are pointing to same memory location
    a=[] # Now, new list is created, pointing to different memory address. 
    a.append(1)
return a # returning new list 

k = [2, 3]  # New list k is created
lol(k)
```

If you print k, you will get [2,3]. It has not been changed by lol() at all.